# can't access localhost:8080 public folder from browser (java spring boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot

i have a java spring boot application that have functionality to save files in "src/main/resources/public/myFiles" path. Now i want to access files and i tried to access the file by typing "http://localhost:8080/public/myFiles" and i'm getting an error saying below.

> Whitelabel Error Page
>   This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>   No message available

Comment: What is the purpose of accessing those files? Do you intend to open them in a new tab or download them?

Comment: yeah, i'm giving an angular ui to download that file.

Comment: Can you provide the code? So I directly update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to add the location to your static folder in the application.properties

```
spring.resources.static-locations=file:<location>
```

And also to access the file don't give the `static-locations` folder name. you can access it directly if it is not in a subfolder. like this

http://localhost:8080/filename.ext

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access your file if it's not on your static folder location, otherwise you need to specify the exact path and file name to access it.

Comment: i even tried that before posting this question, it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

So I have been making a file sharing web app using Spring Boot and here is how I have facilitated getting files from the database. I will focus specifically on your problem because it is very similar to what I faced a few days ago.

Firstly, I make a POJO class `Files` which has details like `filename`, `lastmodified`, and some others which are not relevant to your problem here.

I get the files from the database using a DAO class, add the above mentioned attributes in an ArrayList and return the ArrayList back to the Controller class. In the Controller class, using `request` object I do the following: `request.setAttribute("files", files);`

Now in my jsp file, I use JSTL to get files like this:

```
<c:forEach var="j" items="${files}">
    <td>
        <a href="resources/files/${j.getFilename()}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">${j.getFile()}</a>
    </td>
</c:forEach>
```

`resources/files/` is the path where my files are stored after being uploaded and using `target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"` enables me to open files (files which the browser allows to be opened such as pdf and text files) in a new tab and those which cannot be opened get automatically downloaded.

Comment: thank you for the reply but I'm using spring boot rest and i'm not working with jsp.